# Запятая в "но если... то"

Tags: запятые, союзы

Простой, казалось бы, вопрос, но не нашёл подтверждения, что ситуация та же, что и  со *"что если... то"* (если есть *то,* то запятая между союзами не ставится). *Итак, в случае с **но** запятая также не нужна?*

Ведь так же говорят, правильно я понимаю?

И ещё возник вопрос: ***то*** в данном случае какая часть речи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, ситуация та же.

1. При двух рядом стоящих подчинительных союзах (или подчинительном союзе и союзном слове), а **также при встрече сочинительного союза и подчинительного (или союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие придаточного предложения не требует перестройки главного предложения (практически – если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза то, так, но, наличие которой требует такой перестройки)**, например:  *А женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и, хотя слова ее были привычными, у Сабурова от них вдруг защемило сердце (Симонов)* (при изъятии придаточного уступительного с союзом хотя предложно-местоименное сочетание от них становится неясным, но в структурном отношении такое изъятие возможно, поэтому запятая между сочинительным и подчинительным союзами в подобных случаях обычно ставится).

Если же за придаточным предложением следует вторая часть двойного союза, то запятая между предшествующими двумя союзами не ставится, например: *Ноги женщины были обожжены и босы, **и когда** она говорила, **то** рукой подгребала теплую пыль к воспаленным ступням, словно пробуя этим утишить боль (Симонов)* (при изъятии или перестановке придаточного времени с союзом когда рядом окажутся слова и и то).

2. Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом (после точки) и союзом подчинительным, например: И кто вы такой, я знаю; А зачем это говорится, мне непонятно. Возможность постановки запятой после других присоединительных союзов связана с интонационно-смысловым выделением придаточного предложения, например: Однако, если вы так настаиваете на своем предложении, я готов его принять.

https://studfiles.net/preview/4127827/

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188

ТО здесь тоже вторая часть двойного союза **если... то**.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! А какие во 2-м пункте присоединительные союзы?

Comment: И (И кто...), а (А зачем...) Здесь явно присоединительные конструкции, союзы И и А здесь не соединяют однородные члены или простые предложения в сложном, они же стоят в самом начале предложения.

Comment: Ну да, это интуитивно понятно, я бы запятой не поставил, даже если бы меня во время страшного сна разбудили.